# Cannot write to file I created myself

Tags: php

I have this piece of code:

```
$fp = fopen("/path/to/file", "a+");
if (!$fp) {
        fwrite($fp, "somedata\n");
        fclose($fp);
} else {
        echo "cannot open";
}
```

and the result is an empty file and the message `cannot open`. I have SELinux disabled and the permissions seem OK, otherwise the file wouldn't be created, I'd say.

Any ideas?

Comment: `if (!$fp)` -> `if ($fp)` maybe?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious mistake:

```
if (!$fp) {
```

should be

```
if ($fp) {
```

Comment: Thank you. I will go in the corner now.